# Finding a number that repeats even no of times where all the other numbers repeat odd no of times

Tags: algorithm

Given is an array of integers. Each number in the array repeats an ODD number of times, but only 1 number is repeated for an EVEN number of times. Find that number.

I was thinking a hash map, with each element's count. It requires O(n) space. Is there a better way?

Comment: Since 0 is even, there will be infinitely many integers that occur an even number of times in the array.

Comment: Considering that the numbers are in the array, you are only counting the numbers which are present int he array.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hash-map is fine, but all you need to store is each element's count modulo 2.
All of those will end up being 1 (odd) except for the 0 (even) -count element.

(As Aleks G says you don't need to use arithmetic (`count++ %2`), only xor (`count ^= 0x1`); although any compiler will optimize that anyway.)

Comment: Apparently there is a solution in O(n) time and O(1) space. See here : http://www.careercup.com/question?id=5707243546738688 -- it seems to be doable using XOR. Any ideas ? been thinking about it but no clue so far !!

Comment: ^ @Myna, please post that as an answer!

Answer (score 3):

You don't need to keep the number of times each element is found - just whether it's even or odd number of time - so you should be ok with 1 bit for each element.  Start with 0 for each element, then flip the corresponding bit when you encounter the element.  Next time you encounter it, flip the bit again.  At the end, just check which bit is 1.

Comment: As you said numbers should be bounded, for example if one number is 2^30 you should have a list of size 2^30 which is not good (this is skip list and counting sort idea but it doesn't work without bounds).

Answer (score 3):

I don't know what the intended meaning of "repeat" is, but if there is an even number of occurrences of **(all-1)** numbers, and an odd number of occurances for **only one** number, then XOR should do the trick.

Comment: Exactly.  Just bitwise xor everything together.

Comment: Are you intentionally answering a different question, or did you misread?

Comment: @gsingh2011: No. It is about language. A number that occurs N times is repeated N-1 times. (the first occurence is not a repetition, the second is).

Answer (score 1):

If all numbers are repeated even times and one number repeats odd times, if you `XOR` all of the numbers, the odd count repeated number can be found.

By your current statement I think hashmap is good idea, but I'll think about it to find a better way. (I say this for positive integers.)

Comment: Not the downvoter, but you have the problem description reversed. Only one number is repeated an even number of times, not odd.

Comment: @Chris Mennie, I didn't reversed it, I say if it was so it can be done in this way but for current problem statement I have no idea except hashmap, I mentioned that in my answer. I just say this to help OP if he also has reverse situation.

Comment: Fair enough, I agree with what you said. The inverse problem is more straight forward to solve.

Answer (score 0):

Apparently there is a solution in O(n) time and O(1) space, since it was asked at a software engineer company with this constraint explictly. See here : [Bing interview question](http://careercup.com/question?id=5707243546738688) -- it seems to be doable using XOR over numbers in the array. Good luck ! :)