# Find number occuring even number of times?

Tags: algorithm

Given an array of positive integers. All numbers occur odd number of times except one number which occurs even number of times. Is there any way to find the number in O(n) time & constant space.

Example:

`> I/P = [1, 2, 3, 3]

 O/P = 3`

**The numbers are not sorted and within the range of 10000.**

Comment: Do you have the upper/lower border on each integer?

Comment: Also, are the numbers sorted?

Comment: The opposite problem where every number occurs even number of times, and one number occurs odd number of times, can be solved very easily. I am not sure about this one, though.

Comment: As dasblinkenlight says, if only one number occurs an odd number of times, you can bitwise XOR everything and the result is the one odd number. This looks more interesting.

Comment: @DouglasZare - I'm glad you posted the solution to the other case - I was wondering what it'd be.

Comment: It has been asked before here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7292965/finding-a-number-that-repeats-even-no-of-times-where-all-the-other-numbers-repea although some answers were for the reverse. No one found a constant space algorithm. A version has been asked here: http://www.careercup.com/question?id=5707243546738688 Some answers claimed to use constant space, but they assumed the numbers are from 0-31.

Comment: There's a communication complexity argument that rules out a constant-space single-pass streaming algorithm like XOR.

Comment: Even the XOR with one num occurring even times needs logarithmic space on the size of maximum int `M`. If we consider `M` constant then we can create a random access array of `M` bits to solve the problem. This is still constant space.

Comment: Simple: create an array of 20.000 bits, two for each possible number. Set the first bit to 1 the first time you encounter a number, and toggle the other bit each time you encounter a number. Afterwards any bits that are 10 means present and even number of occurrences. Note that in the problem description the upper boundary on the number values is not dependent on N.

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen 20000 with one pass, if you allow another pass you need 10000 bits.

Comment: @JuniorCompressor Please explain how that would work?

Comment: With the second pass you'll check only the numbers that are present in the input array. When a zero is found then this our number.

Comment: Ah, like that, yes, now I understand.