# Find the Letters Occurring Odd Number of Times

Tags: python, algorithm, dictionary, lookup

I came across a funny question, I am wondering whether we can solve it.

### The Background

In time complexity **O(n)**, can we find the letters occurring odd number of times, Output a list contain letters and **keep the order of letters consistent with original string**.

**In case of multiple options to choose from, take the last occurence as the unpaired character.**

Here is an example:

```
# note we should keep the order of letters
findodd('Hello World')   ==  ["H", "e", " ", "W", "r", "l", "d"] # it is good
findodd('Hello World')   ==  ["H", "l", " ", "W", "r", "e", "d"] # it is wrong
```

### My attempt

```
def findodd(s):
    hash_map = {}

    # This step is a bit strange. I will show an example:
    # If I have a string 'abc', I will convert string to list = ['a','b','c']. 
    # Just because we can not use dict.get(a) to lookup dict. However, dict.get('a') works well.
    s = list(s)

    res = []
    for i in range(len(s)):
        if hash_map.get(s[i]) == 1:
            hash_map[s[i]] = 0
            res.remove(s[i])
        else:
            hash_map[s[i]] = 1
            res.append(s[i])

    return res
findodd('Hello World')
```

Out:

```
["H", "e", " ", "W", "r", "l", "d"]
```

However, since I use `list.remove`, the time complexity is above O(n) in my solution.

### My Question:

1. Can anyone give some advice about **O(n)** solution?
2. If I don't wanna use `s = list(s)`, how to iterate over a string `'abc'` to lookup the value of `key = 'a'`  in a dict? **`dict.get('a')` works but `dict.get(a)` won't work.**

### Source

Here are 2 webpage I watched, however they did not take the order of letter into account and did not provide O(n) solution.

1. [find even time number, stack overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7292965/finding-a-number-that-repeats-even-no-of-times-where-all-the-other-numbers-repea)
2. [find odd time number, geeks for geeks](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/find-the-number-occurring-odd-number-of-times/)

Comment: I the example you gave, I think "l" should be after the letter "e" not after "r".

Comment: @schlodinger Add one more sentence to clarify. In "Hello World" case, we should put `l` in its last occurance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Python 3.7 up has dictionary keys input ordered. Use [collection.OrderedDict](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/collections.html#collections.OrderedDict) for lower python versions.

Go through your word, add letter do dict if not in, else delete key from dict.

Solution is the dict.keys() collection:

```
t = "Hello World"

d = {}
for c in t:
    if c in d:       # even time occurences: delete key
        del d[c]
    else:
        d[c] = None  # odd time occurence: add key

print(d.keys())
```

Output:

```
dict_keys(['H', 'e', ' ', 'W', 'r', 'l', 'd'])
```

Its O(n) because you touch each letter in your input exactly once - lookup into dict is O(1).

There is some overhead by key adding/deleting. If that bothers you, use a counter instead and filter the key() collection for those that are odd - this will make it O(2*n) - 2 is constant so still O(n).

Answer (score 0):

Here is an attempt (keys are ordered in python 3.6 dict):

```py
from collections import defaultdict

def find_odd(s):
    counter = defaultdict(int)
    for x in s:
        counter[x] += 1
    return [l for l, c in counter.items() if c%2 != 0]
```

the complexity of this algo is less than 2n, which is O(n)!

**Example**

```py
>>> s = "hello world"
>>> find_odd(s)
['h', 'e', 'l', ' ', 'w', 'r', 'd']
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use the hash map to store the index at which a character occurs, and toggle it when it already has a value.

And then you just iterate the string again and only keep those letters that occur at the index that you have in the hash map:

```
from collections import defaultdict

def findodd(s):
    hash_map = defaultdict(int)
    for i, c in enumerate(s):
        hash_map[c] = 0 if hash_map[c] else i+1
    return [c for i, c in enumerate(s) if hash_map[c] == i+1]
```

Answer (score 0):

### My solution from scratch

It actually uses the feature that a `dict` in `Python 3.6` is key-ordered.

```
def odd_one_out(s):

    hash_map = {}
    # reverse the original string to capture the last occurance
    s = list(reversed(s))
    res = []
    for i in range(len(s)):
        if hash_map.get(s[i]):
            hash_map[s[i]] += 1

        else:
            hash_map[s[i]] = 1
    for k,v in hash_map.items():
        if v % 2 != 0:
            res.append(k)

    return res[::-1]
```

### Crazy super short solution

```
#from user FArekkusu on Codewars
from collections import Counter

def find_odd(s):
    d = Counter(reversed(s))
    return [x for x in d if d[x] % 2][::-1]
```

Answer (score 0):

Using Counter from collections will give you an O(n) solution. And since the Counter object is a dictionary (which keeps the occurrence order), your result can simply be a filter on the counts:

```
from collections import Counter

text = 'Hello World'
oddLetters = [ char for char,count in Counter(text).items() if count&1 ]
print(oddLetters) # ['H', 'e', 'l', ' ', 'W', 'r', 'd']
```